# How to make IP validation for QtGui.QInputDialog.GetText()

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I am writing code in PySide which has a button "Change IP". When the button is clicked a dialog box appears which has text box. I want validation on the text box which only to accept IP address.

I am using this code:

```
QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, "Title", "Enter IP: ")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIR, `QInputDialog.getText` does not support on-the-fly validation, but if you are willing to roll your own dialog, you could use [QRegExpValidator](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QRegExpValidator.html#qregexpvalidator)

1.Look up the needed regex on the Internets ([here](http://blog.markhatton.co.uk/2011/03/15/regular-expressions-for-ip-addresses-cidr-ranges-and-hostnames/), for instance).
See that it looks like

`^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$` for IP4

2. Create QRegExp object, like this:

`rx = QRegExp("regular_expression_string_from_step_1")`

3.Create `QRegExpValidator` instance and pass the `rx` object to it's constructor, like this:

```
my_validator = QRegExpValidator(rx)
```

4. Call `my_line_edit.setValidator(my_validator)`

That's it, `my_line_edit` should now refuse entry of non-valid IP adresses. If you don't want to go this way, you could just use python's own [re moodule](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) for post-factum validation using the regex from step 1.